# Euler-Bernoulli cantilever beam with parabolic load

Tags: differential-equations, engineering

How do I get the displacement in the free end of a bar with Parabolic load (I.e. in point with length L)?

I found the information on [a site](http://sameradeeb.srv.ualberta.ca/beam-structures/plane-beam-approximations/#comment-2289), but only I found for uniform load.

Someone who understands about engineering could I describe the steps?

[image]

The code obtained was this for uniform load:

```
Clear[a, x, V, M, y, L, EI]
M = EI*D[y[x], {x, 2}]; 
V = EI*D[y[x], {x, 3}]; 
th = D[y[x], {x}]; 
q = -a; 
M1 = M /. x -> 0; 
M2 = M /. x -> L; 
V1 = V /. x -> 0; 
V2 = V /. x -> L; 
y1 = y[x] /. x -> 0; 
y2 = y[x] /. x -> L; 
th1 = th /. x -> 0; 
th2 = th /. x -> L; 
s = DSolve[{EI*Derivative[4][y][x] == 0, M2 == Mom, V2 == PP,y1 == 0, th1 == 0}, y, x]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First find an equation for the parabolically distributed load:

```
param = Thread[a*#^2 + b*# + c & /@ {0, L/3, L} == {Q, Q/2, 0}] // Solve[#, {a, b, c}] &

q[x_] := a*x^2 + b*x + c /. param[[1]]
```

This is the governing equation for Euler-Bernoulli beam:

```
eqn = EI*D[y[x], {x, 4}] == q[x]
```

Boundary conditions are: y[0]==0, y'[0]=0, y''[L]==0 and y'''[L]==0

```
soln1 = DSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[L] == 0, 
y'''[L] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

Equation for cantilever deflection is:

```
defln[x_] = y[x] /. soln1[[1]] // Simplify@# &
```

Tip deflection is given by:

```
defln[L]

(* (3 L^4 Q)/(160 EI) *)
```

Comment: Today again this answer is helping me. Even after more than a year ...

Comment: Today again this answer is helping me. Even after 4 years ...